# Can't find transistor-based PLL circuit example

Tags: transistors, pll

I am learning electronics as a hobby. My current interest is phase locked loops (PLL.) I was able to find a lot of block diagrams with explanations of how PLLs work and also CD4046 based PLL implementations.

Are there example circuits of PLLs made of transistors (not ICs like CD4046?) I've tried to google it with no luck. Maybe some good books? It should preferably be a complete circuit of a PLL, not just separate block/blocks of it.

Comment: The fact you only see it in block diagrams might mean its too complicated to treat the whole as a bunch of transistors. That means you need to look at each block individually, and look at what transistors make up each block.

Comment: I did find this though https://www.brainkart.com/article/Monolithic-PLL-IC-565-applications_36027/

Comment: No everything is delivered on a plate. But combine https://www.electronics-tutorial.net/Mini-Projects/Phase-Locked-Loop/ with this https://hackaday.io/project/8449-hackaday-ttlers/log/150147-bipolar-xor-gate-with-only-2-transistors and you should be pretty close.

Comment: Olds one like RF MC1648 ... MC4024 ... MC4044 ...

Answer (score 1):

*It should preferably be a complete circuit of a PLL, not just separate block/blocks of it.*

On the other hand, it makes much sense to divide the PLL system in separate blocks. This makes it easier to understand the principle - and it makes easier for you to search for a realization based on transistors only.

Remember, what you need is the following:

- A voltage-controlled oscillator
- A suitable loop filter
- A phase discriminator (e.g. a multiplier)

In principle, it should be possible to use only lumped transistors for these three blocks. However, if it makes sense (from the realization/performance point of view) is another question.

(I remember that in the nineteen-sixties we have build transistor-based PLLs for space applications)